# file inclusion with header guard instead of filename possible in C?

Tags: c

In C, we can include a file as `#include "filename.h"`
But for instance if the `filename.h` has the contents as -

```
#ifndef FILE_NAME_GUARD

#define FILE_NAME_GUARD

//contents
.
.
.
```

In my another file, can I include the above file as `#include <FILE_NAME_GUARD>` instead of `#include "filename.h"`?

I tried this way and I was surprised to see that there was no compiler error or linker error. But there was this warning:

```
FILE_NAME_GUARD: No such file or directory
```

Please help in clarifying whether can we include a header with its `multiple_header_guard` name instead of the filename?

Comment: What C compiler issues a mere *warning* for a missing include file?

Answer (score 1):

No - not unless the name you use for the guard macro *precisely* matches the file name. For example, you can include a file like this:

```
#define filename <stdio.h>
#include filename
```

The `filename` will be macro-replaced, so the result be equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

So, if you used a header-guard macro that precisely matched the name of the file to include (including quotes or angle brackets), you could make it work -- but otherwise it'll fail. I don't think it would be a good idea to write code this way. In most cases, it seems to make no sense at all -- the header guard macro will only be defined when that header has already been included, which is exactly the case where you don't (usually) want to include it.

Comment: Good solution, but probably it'd better not to do this, anyway.

Comment: Yeah, but then the header guard would prevent the file from being processed again. And before the file was processed, the guard macro wouldn't be defined, so the #include would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what goes on between the `<>` or `""` in an include statement is pretty much totally implementation defined so you can't say for certain.

Technically an implementation *could* remember which include file mapped to which guard name and intelligently handle that, but I've never seen that in the wild.

And, judging by your warning message, your implementation doesn't do it either.

Comment: @Billy, if by standard, you mean matching what the vast number of implementations do, you're correct. But, if you look at c11, it states "How the places (where include "files" are found - pax) are specified or the header identified is implementation-defined." The only requirement is that the thing inside the delimiters uniquely identify the "file" for inclusion (and it doesn't have to be a physical file at all, it could be injected by the compiler).

Comment: Yes, that is true. But a portable program cannot rely on such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> Please help in clarifying whether can we include the a header with its multiple_header_guard name instead of the filename??

No, you can't, because the preprocessor ain't magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really include a file by its header guard macro.  Normally, the header guard macro is defined as an empty string, and it's hard to include a file named by the empty string.

You can write:

```
#define MAGIC_HEADER "magic.h"
#include MAGIC_HEADER
```

where the macro used after the `#include` matches one of the forms `"name"` or `<name>`.  However, there'd be no point in trying that with header guards.  By the time the header guard macro is defined, you've already included the file and won't want to do so again (with a nod at `<assert.h>` which can be included multiple times with a different effect each time, depending on whether the NDEBUG macro is defined or not).